# Cypress: How do you locate element on hover?

Tags: cypress

I have a "react" app, `#controlsBar` should be visible when mouseover `#video-container`, but the following code failed

```
    cy.get("#controlsBar").should("be.hidden");
    cy.get("#video-container")
      .trigger("mouseover")
      .then((elem) => {

        cy.get(elem).children().eq(3).should("be.visible"); //this is #controlsBar
        //cy.get("#controlsBar").should("be.visible"); //this failed also 
        cy.get("#controlsBar").invoke("show");
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events) package.

1. To Install use `npm install cypress-real-events`.
2. Then under `cypress/support/index.js` file write `import "cypress-real-events/support";`.
3. Then in your test you can write:

```js
cy.get("#video-container").realHover()
```